# Unable to connect to Sybase database from Razor

Tags: razor, jdbc, database-connection, sap-ase

I am current working on a Project that requires Sybase database. Hence I have installed ASE 16.0 Developer's Edition and Razor for easy access but my issue is that my Razor v6.3.19 cannot connect to the sybase. It returns with the error as can be seen on the attached screen

[image]

I can successfully access the database from isql on the terminal. Note that I am running this Ubnutu 14.04 and my database port was set to run on 7160

Sample message from the server log:
00:0006:00000:00009:2015/03/20 21:33:44.65 kernel  network name Server_NAME, interface IPv4, address 127.0.1.1, type tcp, port 7160, filter NONE
Thanks in advance

Comment: Connection refused means that the server isn't listening on the specified port, or your firewall actively prevents you from connecting to that port.

Comment: I am sure the server is running on the specified port from the information gotten fron the log file "network name MyServerName, interface IPv4, address 127.0.1.1, type tcp, port 7160, filter NONE" and I do not have any firewall installed

Comment: `127.0.1.1` is not the same address as `127.0.0.1`, so the port might be open on `127.0.1.1`, but not on `127.0.0.1`. In any case Connection refused is a very low-level error which simply means that the TCP-handshake could not be completed, and that usually means the port is not open.

Comment: WooooW! Thanks @MarkRotteveel for pointing that out. I never thought it be the issue. I felt 127.0.0.1/localhost the only IP I can use to access my system from within. I just confirmed that I can also connect user my server name but not with neither 127.0.0.1 nor localhost. Though it is working but I cant explain why it is working like. I wish someone can clarify that

Comment: All IPv4 address starting with 127 are a local loopback address (as defined in [RFC 1700](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1700.html) ). So all `127.*.*.*` address refer to your local machine, but only `127.0.0.1` is linked to the hostname localhost. When an application listens on a port, it can specify to create the port on all available addresses (`0.0.0.0`) or on a specific address (in this case `127.0.1.1`)

Comment: WooooW! I never know about this until yesterday's event. Thanks @MarkRotteveel for your help. I wish you put this such that I can mark it as the correct answer. That also explained why localhost is not working but my server name and 127.0.1.1 works. I guess there must be a mapping somewhere on my system where 127.0.1.1 was mapped to my serverName and 127.0.0.1 mapped to localhost

Comment: I added an answer based on my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection refused means that the server isn't listening on the specified port, or your firewall actively prevents you from connecting to that port.

Your log shows that the server is listening on `127.0.1.1`; this is not the same address as `127.0.0.1`, so the port might be open on `127.0.1.1`, but not on `127.0.0.1`. Specifying `127.0.1.1` should allow you to connect.

All IPv4 address starting with 127 are a local loopback address (as defined in [RFC 1700](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1700.html)), so all `127.*.*.*` address refer to your local machine, but only `127.0.0.1` is - usually - linked to the hostname `localhost`. When an application listens on a port, it can specify to create the port on all available addresses (`0.0.0.0`) or on a specific address (in this case `127.0.1.1`).